# JOptionPane, exemplo?

Tags: java, swing, gui

Bem, o JOptionPane precisa de todos esses complementos:

```
  JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(parentComponent, message, title,
              optionType, messageType, icon, options, initialValue);
```

Poderiam dar um exemplo de todos esse complementos preenchidos corretamente? Pois não sei oque é `parentComponent`, não sei como usar icon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exemplo bem básico:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class CriaDialogo
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
   // Algo que deseja mostrar (aviso, mensagem de erro)
    String erro = "Erro 404: não foi possível encontrar o batman";

    // Cria um JFrame
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("JOptionPane exemplo");

    // Cria o JOptionPane por showMessageDialog
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
        "Houve um problema ao procurar o batman:\n\n '" + erro + "'.", //mensagem
        "Erro 404", // titulo da janela 
        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

## Explicação:

**parentComponent**:

O JOptionPane precisa de um componente do qual será derivado, o mais comum é usar (e criar um JFrame para isso) que é o que ocorre no exemplo acima. Desta forma a interface do JOptionPane usará o Jframe (ou seja lá qual for a classe pai) para renderizar-se.

**Tipo de mensagem**:

Eu optei por mostrar uma mensagem *informativa* mas poderá escolher qualquer um dos valores dessa lista:

- ERROR_MESSAGE
- INFORMATION_MESSAGE
- WARNING_MESSAGE
- QUESTION_MESSAGE
- PLAIN_MESSAGE

[Sugiro que leia a documentação para ver mais detalhes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html)

De forma análoga poderá usar o JOptionPane para pedir um dado do usuário:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class CriaDialogo
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    // Cria um JFrame
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("JOptionPane exemplo");

    // Cria o JOptionPane por showMessageDialog
    int resposta = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame,"escolha um", "escolha dois", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    //verfica se a resposta é verdadeira
    if (resposta == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Olá");
      }
      else {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Adeus");
         System.exit(0);
      }
    System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

Listas de tipos de mensagem:

- DEFAULT_OPTION
- YES_NO_OPTION
- YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION
- OK_CANCEL_OPTION

E segue a lista de respostas possíveis para isso:

- YES_OPTION
- NO_OPTION
- CANCEL_OPTION
- OK_OPTION
- CLOSED_OPTION

Comment: Mas pode explicar separadamente o que seria ParentComponent?

Answer (score 9):

```
JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(
                           null
                         , "Pergunta?"        // Mensagem
                         , "Titulo"               // Titulo
                         , JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION  
                         , JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE                               
                         , null // Icone. Você pode usar uma imagem se quiser, basta carrega-la e passar como referência
                         , opcoes // Array de strings com os valores de cada botão. Veja o exemplo abaixo **
                         , "Botao 3"    // Label do botão Default
                       );
```

**opcoes** pode ser declarado assim:

```
String[] choices = {"Botao 1", "Botao 2", "Botao 3", "Botao 4"};
```

O **parent component** é apenas para orientar o Dialog a qual janela ela pertence, desta forma ele vai se posicionar em relação a ela. Geralmente usamos NULL para que ela fique no centro do Desktop.

Para exibir uma imagem você pode usar um **BufferedImage**.

**JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION** : Se você passar NULL ao invés de **opcoes** sua dialog vai ter os botões 'YES', 'No' e 'Cancel'

**JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE** é o tipo de mensagem que você vai mostar. Este em especial é um tipo de mensagem com um icone personalizado (pelo parâmetro icon). Existem outros:

```
JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE
JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE
JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE
JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE
JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE
JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE (sem icone)
```