# É possivel chamar uma classe(JFrame) ao apertar okay no JOptionPane?

Tags: java

Gostaria de Abrir outra janela ao apertar okay em JOptionPane 
isso é possível ? se Sim ! me de uma Luz ?

Answer (score 1):

Sim, basta utilizar o método  `showConfirmDialog()`, e validar se o retorno dele é igual ao botáo OK do JOPTIONPANE. Em caso afirmativo, você instancia seu JFrame como qualquer outra classe com `JFrame seuFrame = new JFrame();`

Consulte a documentação da classe JOptionPane para verificar como validar o retorno do botão.

- [Class JOptionPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html)
- [JOptionPane, exemplo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/29404/28595)